# raising events in chaining classes

Tags: events, c++-cli

say I have three classes: class1, control1 and form1; form1 instantiate contorl. and control1 instantiate class1, the later produces some event that I need to 'bypass' to form1, to achieve that I have made an intermediate function as shown below:

```cpp
public delegate void TestHandler(String^ str);
public ref Class class1
{
    event TestHandler^ TestHappen;
    void someFunction()
    {
        TestHappen("test string");
    }
};

public ref Class control1
{
    event TestHandler^ TestHappen;
    class1^ class1Obj;
    control1()
    {
        class1Obj= gcnew class1();
        class1Obj->TestHappen+= gcnew TestHandler(this,&control1::onTest);  
    }   
    void onTest(String^ str)
    {
        TestHappen(str);
    }
};

public ref Class form1
{
    control1^ control1Obj;
    form1()
    {
        control1Obj= gcenw control1();
        control1Obj->TestHappen+= gcnew TestHandler(this,&form1::onTest);
    }
    void onTest(String^ str)
    {
        //do something with the string...
    }
};
```

I don't want to use class1 in form1, are there a way to remove the intermediate onTest() function.

Comment: It is a wee bit of a code smell.  But you've got Control as the hard base class and multiple inheritance isn't supported.  Don't worry about it, you're doing it right.  Bubbling events is not unusual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use a custom event, you can write its add-handler and remove-handler functions so that they add and remove the delegate directly from another object's event.

For example:

```
public ref class control1 // in "ref class", class is lowercase!
{
    class1 class1Obj; // stack-semantics syntax, locks class1Obj lifetime to be same as the containing control1 instance

public:
    event TestHandler^ TestHappen {
        void add(TestHandler^ handler) { class1Obj.TestHappen += handler; }
        void remove(TestHandler^ handler) { class1Obj.TestHappen -= handler; }
    }
};
```